# SQLite3 "forgets" to use foreign keys

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, raspbian

I'm using Ruby with SQLite3 and my attempts to use foreign keys in Sqlite3 were unfortunately not successful. According to `sqlite3 --version`, version 3.7.13 is installed. As far as I know, Sqlite3 supports foreign keys since version 3.6.x.

I know that foreign keys are deactivated by default and have to be activated with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`. In my Ruby db-create-script, I'm doing something like this:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
  CREATE TABLE apps (
    id ....
  );
  CREATE TABLE requests (
    ...
    app_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(app_id) REFERENCES apps(id),
  );
  ...
SQL
db.execute_batch(sql)
```

Unfortunately, I can happily insert rows into `requests` with unknown app-ids, it works, but of course it shouldn't.

Interesting: using the sqlite3 shell directly, I can observe the following behaviour:

```
$ sqlite3 database.db
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1 // as expected
sqlite> .quit
$ sqlite3 database.db
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
0 // off ?!
```

Without quitting the sqlite3 shell, foreign keys **are working** after activating them (and not quitting the shell) and **I'm not allowed** to insert rows with unknown app_ids.

Comment: Related question: if data violating the foreign key constraint are added and subsequently the foreign_keys flag is set to on: does that cause an error?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think I can answer my own question: The documentation says: Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled for **each database connection separately**. Annoying, but it's finally working now.

Comment: PRAGMAs are never saved. With the exception of those with the explicit purpose of setting a file's metadata, they always just have an effect on the current connection.

Answer (score 17):

Put this at the top of the file that executes the SQL commands and it will enable foreign keys on runtime.

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new("database.db")
db.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
```

Answer (score 15):

One way of permanently turning on *foreign_keys* by default is to inject the following line into `~/.sqliterc`:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Please note that it will affect all your databases...

Comment: @MuhammadAdeel the problem with this is that it only enables foreign keys for your user. If other people might use your application, and if it's important that foreign keys are checked, probably better to enforce it where the connection is established.

Comment: I tried this for my flask application, but it didn't work. (And yes, I did restart it and so on.)

Comment: This affects only the interactive client and is thus not useful for development.

Comment: this file doesn't appear to exist in ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 11 uses default SQLite in .env file. Change to MySQL.
then uncomment the following:

- DB_CONNECTION=mysql
- DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
- DB_PORT=3306
- DB_DATABASE=laravel
- DB_USERNAME=root
- DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: What does your answer have to do with the question?